# Warping an image using control points in Octave

Tags: octave, transformation

I have to create a function in Octave that receives a monochromatic image and a matrix with the original points and the destination points.
I've seen other answers but it's not what I have to do exactly.

[image: Example]

This is what I did until now. The matrix "Entrada" are the entry points that I'm using to test.

```
Entrada = [1      1      50      50; 
       1      350    1       300; 
       390    1      390     1;
       390    350    300     350];

L =  [Entrada(1,3);
      Entrada(1,4);
      Entrada(2,3);
      Entrada(2,4);
      Entrada(3,3);
      Entrada(3,4);
      Entrada(4,3);
      Entrada(4,4)]

A = [Entrada(1,1) Entrada(1,2) 1 0 0 0 -(Entrada(1,1) * Entrada(1,3)) -(Entrada(1,2) * Entrada(1,3));
     0 0 0 Entrada(1,1) Entrada(1,2) 1 -(Entrada(1,1) * Entrada(1,4)) -(Entrada(1,2) * Entrada(1,4));
     Entrada(2,1) Entrada(2,2) 1 0 0 0 -(Entrada(2,1) * Entrada(2,3)) -(Entrada(2,2) * Entrada(2,3));
     0 0 0 Entrada(2,1) Entrada(2,2) 1 -(Entrada(2,1) * Entrada(2,4)) -(Entrada(2,2) * Entrada(1,4));
     Entrada(3,1) Entrada(3,2) 1 0 0 0 -(Entrada(3,1) * Entrada(3,3)) -(Entrada(3,2) * Entrada(3,3));
     0 0 0 Entrada(3,1) Entrada(3,2) 1 -(Entrada(3,1) * Entrada(3,4)) -(Entrada(3,2) * Entrada(3,4));
     Entrada(4,1) Entrada(4,2) 1 0 0 0 -(Entrada(4,1) * Entrada(4,3)) -(Entrada(4,2) * Entrada(4,3));
     0 0 0 Entrada(4,1) Entrada(4,2) 1 -(Entrada(4,1) * Entrada(4,4)) -(Entrada(4,2) * Entrada(4,4))]

AT = A';

X = (inv(AT*A))*AT*L;

T = [X(1,1) X(2,1) X(3,1);
     X(4,1) X(5,1) X(6,1);
     X(7,1) X(8,1) 1]
```

I have the transformation Matrix, and I have to associate the original points to the new image. I have to use the transformation matrix to every point and then use homogeneous coordinates correct?

Can anyone help me with this?

Regards

Comment: Please explain the format for Entrada. Each line has 4 values. Is your figure 4-dimensional?

Comment: Hi!
The format for Entrada, using the figure in the example it's this:

A1x A1y B1x B1y
A2x A2y B2x B2y
A3x A3y B2x B2y
A4x A4y B2x B2y

The first and the second collumn are the the entry points of the image that I have to do the transformation and the third and fourth collumn it's the destination points.

I have to create a function that will recieve a image and a matrix like "Entrada" and do the transformation according to these points.

Comment: Basically, I have to do the function imwarp and I have the transformation matrix (T). 
Now I have to aplly T to every point in the image.